# Windows 2003 Service and Timer issues causing Tick not to be called?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, timer, windows-server-2003

Having a few problems with Timers within a service on Win2k3...
Basically, creating a service that every X minutes/seconds, checks for a certain process and whether it is running. I figured the easiest way to get this done was via a Timer.

Have managed to install the service fine, and it seems to be reporting that it is starting/stopping OK. I have written to the eventlog using Eventlog.WriteEntry, and have observed that it is reaching the startup function, but not the Timer Tick.

```
            EventLog.WriteEntry("SETTINGS SET");
            // Set our timer's interval to the value set in the settings.xml file.
            tmrCheck.Interval = Int32.Parse(_settingChkInterval) * 1000;
            // Enable our timer and away we go, checking away!
            tmrCheck.Enabled = true;
            // Set our Tick event to our Tick void
            tmrCheck.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrCheck_Tick_1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmmm, you cant use a Winform timer in a service.

You need to use `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`.